# Is it possible to print the log of other application in our android applicaion?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, developer-tools

I want to print the log of other application into our application logcat. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.

[As of Android 4.1 Jelly Bean](https://nolanlawson.com/2012/09/02/catlog-jives-with-jelly-bean-goes-open-source/), for security reasons, on a non-rooted device, you can only access your own application's logs.  If this were not the case, malicious apps could potentially sniff logs for secrets like passwords or authentication tokens (which should not be logged, but it's a common mistake for apps to do so anyway, hence this security measure).